# Customize the InfoPath form of an External Content List

Tags: infopath, external-content-type, external-list

I generated an InfoPath form which OOTB gives me the ability to edit items in an External List, which in turn, updates a database table.

This form however uses the Sharepoint ribbon control to show the Save and Close buttons (amongst others).

Is there a way for me to put my own Save and Cancel buttons on this form?

Thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out.

1. Open your InfoPath form
2. Click Form Options
3. Choose the "Web Browser" option and uncheck the option to display the ribbon.
4. Drop two button controls on the form.
5. Right click Save button and choose the "Submit" action
6. For the Cancel button you can create a Rule to close the form.

Cheers!

KS